# SpringBoot graphql "Error creating bimap of type => class" error

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I have model and dto classes. I seperated 2 graphqls file (food.graphqls, category.graphqls). Food, includes category. I implemented query and mutatuion resolver classes but i am giving this error:

```
 Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Error creating bimap of type => class
```

My resolver classes like this:

```
@Component
public class CategoryMutationResolver implements GraphQLMutationResolver {

@Component
public class FoodQueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your graphql file. Most likely you defined an input as a type. You should post the contents of your graphql files if you need more insight.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error this week and managed to solved the problem today.

**Issue**: I have defined enums in my schema and declared fields with enum as data type

**Error**: Same as what you encountered

**Solution**: I defined the same enums in my Java side and everything went well.